# The function of the "ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)" part in the Makefile

Tags: makefile

I really don't know the function of the following part:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(DFILES)
endif
```

Here is the possible explanation I get from the GNU make manual:

> to avoid including ‘.d’ files during clean rules, so make won’t create
>   them only to immediately remove them again:

But I don't fully understand "won’t create them only to immediately remove them again".

Here is the Makefile from **derivative.tar.bz2** from http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/03-Initialization,_Listing,_And_Running.php#wherearewegoingtogo:

```
TARGET = driver
# CC     = colorgcc
CC     = gcc
CFILES = $(wildcard *.c)
OFILES = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(CFILES))
DFILES = $(patsubst %.c, .deps/%.d, $(CFILES))
WARN   = -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Waggregate-return \
    -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -pedantic \
    -Wnested-externs -Wredundant-decls -Wwrite-strings -Winline -Werror
CFLAGS = -std=c99 $(WARN) -g3
LDLIBS = -lm


all: $(TARGET)
    ctags *.c *.h

$(TARGET): $(OFILES)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OFILES) $(LDLIBS)


.deps/%.d: %.c
    @mkdir -p .deps
    @$(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; $(RM) -rf $@.$$$$


ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(DFILES)
endif



.PHONY: clean nuke

clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(TARGET) *.o core .deps tags
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose you've just untarred the archive, and for whatever reason you want to run `make clean` before anything else. Presumably, it is already clean. Now, without the `ifneq`, make would:

1. Execute the `include $(DFILES)` line. Before doing the `include` proper, it would...
2. Run the recipe for `.deps/%.d: %.c` because the `$(DFILES)` variable contains files with names that match `.deps/%.d`. This means running `$(CC)` (which is `gcc` by default), which is a rather expensive operation. Once the recipe is run as many times as there are `.d` files to generate, then...
3. Run the recipe for `clean`.

All the work done in 2 is pointless since at step 3 it will be deleted. The reason 2 exists is that when you include a file, make first checks whether it has a recipe to generate the file to be included an runs the recipe if the file does not exist or is out of date.

The `ifneq` bit allows the Makefile to avoid doing the work in step 2 if the goal is `clean`.